# Absolute reRendering using RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, rerender

My problem is that RichFaces `reRender` does not work 'under' the current element in the element tree; only upper elements get rerendered.

Is there any way to access lower elements with AJAX?

Any help would be appreciated!
Daniel

**EDIT** I edited this question to a more general one. See revisions if interested in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example where `changePanel111()` changes the content of a lower element:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="true">
    <rich:panel id="PANEL1">
        <h:outputText id="PANEL1TEXT" value="#{ajaxTestBean.panel1}"/>
        <rich:panel id="PANEL11">
            <h:outputText id="PANEL11TEXT" value="#{ajaxTestBean.panel11}"/>
            <rich:panel id="PANEL111">
                <h:outputText id="PANEL111TEXT" value="#{ajaxTestBean.panel111}"/>
            </rich:panel>
        </rich:panel>
        <rich:panel id="PANEL12">
            <h:outputText id="PANEL12TEXT" value="#{ajaxTestBean.panel12}"/>
            <br/>
            <a4j:commandLink value="CHANGE PANEL12" action="#{ajaxTestBean.changePanel12}">
                <a4j:support reRender="PANEL12" event="onclick"/>
            </a4j:commandLink>
            <br/>
            <a4j:commandLink value="CHANGE PANEL111" action="#{ajaxTestBean.changePanel111}">
                <a4j:support reRender="form:PANEL111" event="onclick"/>
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </rich:panel>
    </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

Notice how the lower element needs to be identified as `form:PANEL111`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

- `reRender` works with providing an the `id` of the target object you want to reRender (inside the same naming container - `form` most often)
- the `id` should be a unique string, according to html spec
- `reRender` allows dynamic value - i.e. `reRender="#{myBean.currentItemsToRerender}`

Based on that I think you should be able to achieve what you want (although it's not entirely clear)

**Update:**

[`UIComponent.findComponent(..)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) has a well-defined algorithm for resolving ids. So for absolute referencing your reRendered id should *start with* `:` and then continue through the hierarchy of the naming containers.

Answer (score 0):

reRender can point to any component outside the form as well. For example this works:

```
<h:form>
  <a4j:commandButton reRender="panel"/>
</h:form>

<h:panelGrid id="panel">
...
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my MyFaces+Richfaces App, `<rich:panel>` tag was not working as described in the selected answer. When I changed it to `<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" />`, it started working as given here  "[<a4j:commandLink> Not Rerendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938748/a4jcommandlink-not-rerendering)"

Configuration: MyFaces 2.1.10(Facelets used for templating) and Richfaces 4.2.3.

Hope this will help.