# how to rerender a4j:commandLink after the action has been completed

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, seam2

i have a very simple code here:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{ticketAboxEventHelper.removeAboxTicket(ticketAbox)}"
                             onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure ... ?')) return false;"
                             reRender="aboxlistpanel">
                        <h:graphicImage alt="Delete" url="../../img/dialog-error-5.png" title="Delete" />
                        <a4j:support event="oncomplete" 
                                     action="#{editTicketNewAction.testRerender()}" 
                                     reRender="aboxlistpanel"
                                     />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

When the link clicked the system must

1. ask if the user is confirmed
2. do the action
3. rerender the aboxlistpanel

Now my problem is the rerendering is hapenning before the action is getting finished. any idea how it can be done in the right way?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<a4:support>` from your `<a4j:commandLink>`?

Comment: yes it rerenders first and then does the action, but i want the action first and then to rerender

Comment: That's really strange. The execution order is `onclick`, `action`, `reRender`, `oncomplete`. Are you sure there's no other component that also fires the rerendering of the `aboxlistpanel` or of the whole page?

Comment: the `<a4j:log />` could help you to see where the AJAX is blocking...

Comment: `action="#{editTicketNewAction.testRerender()}"` This is not JSF 1.2 valid, I am right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I wrapped the offending JSF code in a  and everything began working as expected. related to answer [<a4j:commandLink> Not Rerendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938748/a4jcommandlink-not-rerendering?rq=1). i solved it first and then found out someone else solved it in the same way. hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Your action methods is not valid for JSF 1.2 and you don't need the `<a4j:support>`. Since you want to pass a parameter, you should use `<f:attribute />` and `actionListener` :

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{ticketAboxEventHelper.removeAboxTicket}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure ... ?')) return false;" reRender="aboxlistpanel">
    <h:graphicImage alt="Delete" url="../../img/dialog-error-5.png" title="Delete" />
    <f:attribute name="ticket" value="#{ticketAbox}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Your bean method will look like this :

```
public void removeAboxTicket(ActionEvent event)
{
    TicketAbox ticket = (TicketAbox)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("ticket");

    // Your business logic
}
```

**More info :**

- [How to pass parameters in method expression JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-in-method-expression-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: no its fine, i am using seam 2 and jboss el expressions, so they work fine. but thanks for your input anyway