# How to re-render component in a different h:form?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, primefaces

I know there is a attribute called "update", I can use it like this, `update="another component's id"`, but this doesn't work when they are in different `<h:form>` tags.

For example, the code like this,

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:define name="">

        <div>

        <h:form>

            <p:panel header="">
                <h:panelGrid id="display">
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

        </h:form>

        <h:form>

            <p:dialog id="dialog">
                <p:dataTable onRowSelectUpdate="aa.bb.display"></p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>

        </div>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I mean, how can I write in the site of "aa.bb.display", it will re-render the panelGrid of "display" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give an id to the `<h:form>`. It is important, since you **HAVE TO** reference like `formId:display`

My question on this: [Absolute reRendering using RichFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154943/absolute-rerendering-using-richfaces), check my answer. I tested this also in PrimeFaces.